# Is Self-Service password change allowed for Azure AD free accounts synced using AD Connect?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am using free Azure AD and when a user tries to "Change password" in the Azure portal, it says:

"you can’t change your password here. Your organization doesn’t allow you to change your password on this site. Please change your password according to the method recommended by your organization, or ask your admin if you need help."

All I can find online is that a change was made and now this feature requires Password Writeback (a premium feature) to work however it is advertised as being available with free Azure AD https://azure.microsoft.com/en-ca/pricing/details/active-directory/ (Self-Service Password Change for cloud users).

Am I missing something here? Is there a possible workaround, or is this feature really not available to Azure AD/AD Connect environments without premium? Again, I am only looking to have users change passwords not reset them.

Answer (score 1):

Password change (not reset)  is available in Free edition of Azure AD.

This link has few of the the scenarios listed:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-sspr-licensing

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/user-help/active-directory-passwords-update-your-own-password#change-my-password